# How to differentiate this

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$e^{\tfrac{1}{\sin x}}$$
Help me how to differentiate that please help me Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the chain rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the [chain rule](http://quantizd.blogspot.com/p/blog-page%5f7049.html). You may also have to know that: $$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}e^x=e^x\quad\color{grey}{\text{and}}\quad\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\dfrac1{\sin x}=-\cot x\csc x.$$
And in case you forgot: $$\csc x\equiv \dfrac1{\sin x}\quad\color{grey}{\text{and}}\quad\cot x\equiv \dfrac1{\tan x}.$$

I hope this helps. 
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Comment: thanks I got $e^{\csc x}(-\cot x\csc x)$ is it correct?

Comment: @user142648 Excellent! That's the exact answer, keep up the good work! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Recall the chain rule:
$$\dfrac{d f(g(x))}{dx} = \left.\dfrac{df(y)}{dy} \right\vert_{y=g(x)} \cdot \dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}$$
In your case, $f(y) = e^y$ and $g(x) = \csc(x)$. I trust you know how to differentiate these functions and complete the answer.

Comment: thanks is $e^{\csc x}(-\cot x\csc x)$ the answer?

Comment: @user142648 Yes.

Comment: haha differentiation is easy :D

Answer (score 0):

Another way: define $f=e^{\frac{1}{\sin x}}$ and take log to get $Lf=\frac{1}{\sin x}$. It's a much easier function to differentiate. Now keep in mind that $(\log f(x))'_{x}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$. Can you handle from here?

Comment: What does $(\log f(x))_x'$ denote? I mean that x in subscript

Comment: take a derivative of $\log$ function. Can you do it?

Comment: Yes I know from our course that $derivative\,\log_b x=\frac{1}{x\log_e(b)}$

Comment: This is an extension of this idea for $f(x)$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff%28log%28f%28x%29%29%2Cx%29

Comment: thanks I like your technique I got the same answer as with the chain rule

Comment: You are welcome